# When I am using the grid I used half the screen width and screen height but I got these errors tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Anyone please solve this

```
halfwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 
column1 = halfwidth
loadinglabel = tkinter.Label(cv, text="Loading...", bg="#99D9EA", font=fontStyle) 
loadinglabel.grid(row=200, column=column1)
```

I get this error

[image: view the error png]

Comment: Are you aware that the `row` and `column` attributes aren't in units of pixels? They are abstract values which represent relative column numbers. Setting the column to 1, 100, 1000, or 10000 will yield the same result if all of the other columns are empty.

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, an `integer` is required but `column1` (which is assigned value of `halfwidth`) is a float number.

You can get an integer for `halfwidth` using integer division `//`:

```
halfwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()//2
```

or cast the float result to integer using `int()`:

```
halfwidth = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2)
```

or

```
column1 = int(halfwidth)
```

Note that `loadinglabel.grid(row=200, column=column1)` may not put the label at the center position horizontally.  You can use `place()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @acw1668 said you cannot use float values with tkinter keywords. So use `//` instead of `/` or convert the last value to an `int(your_value)`